# I said (that) I would

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, reported-speech

Do the following sentences mean the same and can I use them interchangeably? And can 'that' be omitted in the first sentence?

1- I said (that) I would go to the meeting on August 25, 2017.

2- I said, "I will go to the meeting on August 25, 2017."

Comment: Yes, yes, and yes. But 1, out of context, is ambiguous: it's not certain whether your meeting or the speech occurred on 8/25/17. 2 is not ambiguous.

Comment: One more quetion, Are both these sentences ok and do they mean the same?  1- She said to me, "You are not my friend anymore. You can go now."                                               2- She told me, "You are not my friend anymore. You can go now."

Comment: Sentence (2) in your second example is grammatically incorrect.  If you want it’s meaning to be similar to (1) you should have: `”She told me that I was not her friend anymore and that I could go now.”`

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) don't mean the same thing. Sentence (2) means that I said those exact words while sentence (1) tells the meaning of what I said but it doesn't have the exact words that were spoken.

"That" is optional.  If the sentence was more complicated you might use it to remove any ambiguity but it is not needed here.